# Using MVC and have questions about roles of domain entities and mvc components

Tags: model-view-controller, architecture

I have an MVC application which has the following architecture...

UI Project (MVC)
   Controllers (C) - instantiates view models
   ViewModels (M) - primary vehicle for feeding data to views
   Views

Business Layer
   Returns data from Repository layer and returns entity/model objects

Entity/Model Layer (Domain Entity Layer)

Repository Layer (  Data Layer)
   Data access and returns entity/model objects to business layer

So, with the above architecture **what interacts with the business layer?** (viewmodels or controllers).

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to sort through your terminology, I'll say that in java (and I think you'll see how this generally applies) the following structure is usually used:

Controllers are mapped to urls, and validate parameters. They delegate business logic to service classes. The service classes return models, which the controller passes to the view for rendering.

The service classes have dependency on the dao/repository layer, which does some kind of db lookup to get model objects and applies some business logic to it.

So back to your example, it's the controllers that interact with the business layer. The idea is to keep business logic out of the controller AND out of the dao layers.

Comment: Yes, I grasp what you are saying.  

I am currently using ViewModels (which may provide one domain models to the view).  This is very much like Variant #2 at this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/01/26/view-models-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

I am using viewmodels cause it would seem odd to load up my domain objects purely for migrating data to the view.  With viewmodels i can structure i such a way to facilitate view construction.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is responsible to get the data, construct the viewmodel using that data and pass that Viewmodel to the view. To do that, you can inject the needed service into your controller, which talks to your service layer or business layer if you don't have a service layer.

In fact, to get data, you don't need your business layer or domain objects. You could create a query service that returns the data as needed by your views, which makes it easy to get data without the overhead of a domain model, which you don't need for querying (command query separation).